# Richedit control htmltext table formatting

Tags: c#, htmltext, richedit-control

I am using richeditcontrol in C#. I want to display a table(html) in this control. I did it but now I want to change font size and color of celltext, it did not work :/

Here is my code:

```
String htmlBilgi = "<table><tbody style=color:purple>";
htmlBilgi += "<tr><td font:5px>Ad</td><td>Deniz</td><td>Soyad</td><td>Eliacik</td></tr>";
htmlBilgi += "<tr><td>MEslek</td><td>Ogretmen</td><td>Yas</td><td>28"</td></tr>";
htmlBilgi += "</tbody></table>";
recBilgi.HtmlText = htmlBilgi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use styles:

```
<td style=\"font-size:5px\">
```